# Example of non abelian group with property $h^3 = e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

It's obvious that if for every element $g$ of group $G$ we have property
$$
g^2 = e
$$
then $G$ is abelian. Does there exist an example of non-abelian group $H$ where for every element $h$ we have property:
$$h^3 = e$$